# $UCOUNT\leq_{cd} BCOUNT$

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, circuits

Suppose we are given $n$ bits $a_0,\dots, a_{n-1}$. Then let $s=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}$ Then $BCOUNT(a_0,\dots,a_{n-1})=s$ and $UCOUNT(a_0,\dots,a_{n-1})=1^s0^{n-s}$ Now i have to show that $UCOUNT\leq_{cd} BCOUNT$ i.e. $UCOUNT$ is constant depth circuit reducible to $BCOUNT$. I have to create a constant depth circuit which uses $BCOUNT$ as gates and  then show that it computes $UCOUNT$.

I cant think of any way to show that this is possible in constant depth.